# Novel/series: most of Earth is uninhabitable, other than alien resort spots

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm seeking author and titles. The setup is that, due (I think) to war, most of earth has become uninhabitable, but the inhabitable parts are resort spots for an alien race. I was browsing it on Amazon; author and work I think fairly well-known; not very recent--I stupidly did not instantly make a note. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is very (very) little information to go on. Is there *anything* else you remember about the book? Was it in English? Where and when was it set? Where did the aliens come from? Anything at all about the plot? You may be interested in checking out [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on writing a good story-ID question.

Comment: I was thinking "Battlefield Earth" by L. Ron Hubbard, but it doesn't really deal with resorts that aliens go to. Instead, for those that are interested, it is about a group of humans that decide to fight back against their captors (a superior, human-like alien race) and take back their planet (aka Earth). The 1080 page novel follows this group of human beings as they go from the enslaved to roman like warriors, and begin to rebuild the world. A great, and long, novel that I might recommend :) Not to get mixed up with the movie, starring John Travolta. The movie was GOD AWFUL!!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's a well-known work, that sounds to me like *This Immortal* by Roger Zelazny.  Much of the Earth has been rendered uninhabitable by nuclear warfare, and the capital of the planet is located in Port-au-Prince.  There are aliens who visit the Earth's remaining resorts in large numbers, and the protagonist had bombed one or more of the resorts years before the story takes place.  A lot of the conflict in the story is about what the future status of the planet is going to be, with most humans now living off world and the Earth having become a playground for rich alien vacationers.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, Zelazny. Duh. :) I thought it was classic and obvious--it just escaped me.

Comment: @SGC If you found Buzz's answer helpful, please [accept it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the little grey checkmark symbol next to it